# cordova saveToPhotoAlbum changes the name of the picture

Tags: android, cordova

env: cordova-2.9.0rc1, android 4.4

I use the following code:

```
        navigator.camera.getPicture(
            that.uploadPhoto,
            that.onCaptureFail, {
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: true
            }
        );
```

it works fine *ONLY* that there is a race condition:
the saveToPhotoAlbum apparently change the name of the picture,
therefore the uploadPhoto fail (if it happens after the saveToPhotoAlbum).

This is an educated guess about what really going on there...

any info, or solution is welcome

I will try to upgrade cordova to see if it solve this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that cordova upgrade (to 5.1.1) solve this issue.